# Creating all permutations of list with "alignment"

Tags: list-manipulation, permutation

I need to find all permutations of a list satisfying a condition but I'm lost about how to do so. Given a list I want a write a function to produce all permutations such that the list is "top aligned" and has all permutations of the elements. I think the second requirement of having all permutations of the elements is straightforward using replacements, but I'm not sure how to do the first. Here I give two examples of what I want the output to look like (I used `Grid` only to increase the clarity of the output)

```
MyPermute[{{"a","b"}}]=
```

[image]

```
MyPermute[{{"a","b","c"}}]=
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

I think the above two examples are insufficient to fully specify the output I want. If the permutation function was run on four elements I'd want to include output such as:

[image]

Comment: Should it also include `{{a},{a,b},{c}}`, i.e. the length of rows not decreasing?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer: No it should always be top aligned (no gaps, like an upside down game of connect-four)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fills the blanks with 0s:

```
 myPerms[list_] := 
 Flatten[Table[
   ArrayReshape[#, {i, Length[list] + 1 - i}] & /@ 
   Permutations[list],
 {i, Length[list]}], 1]
```

Now doing

```
MatrixForm /@ myPerms[{"a", "b", "c"}]
```

reproduces what you want in the second case. I have assumed you only want rectangular arrays here. If you want to allow the lengths of different rows to be different, you can use `IntegerPartitions[Length[list]]` to calculate all possible lengths of rows.

**UPDATE**

As I suspected, OP also need tables with rows of different lengths. I'm sure there is a much better way to do this, but I couldn't think of one right now. First, the following function takes a permutation, and a list of lengths of rows, and returns the table:

```
pL[list_, rowlens_] := 
First@Last@
  Reap[FoldList[(Sow[#1[[1 ;; #2]]]; #1[[#2 + 1 ;;]]) &, list,rowlens]]
```

E.g. `pL[{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}, {3, 1, 1}]` returns

> {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d"}, {"e"}}

Now we just apply this to all permutations of the original list, and let the row length specs be the integer partitions of the length of the original list:

```
myPerms2[list_] := 
Flatten[Table[
  pL[perm, intpart], {intpart, IntegerPartitions[Length[list]]},
  {perm, Permutations[list]}], 1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think this is in the right direction, but its still missing a few elements I had in mind (see edit). This might be solved by using your suggested `IntegerPartitions[Length[list]]`, but I'm not sure how to get this to work.

Comment: Thanks it the update seems to work just as desired. Just a quick comment I don't think you need the `Flatten` in `Flatten@intpart`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, you are right of course. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

```
per = Permutations[{"a", "b", "c"}];

Grid[{Row /@ per}, Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

```
Grid[{Column /@ per}, Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

```
Grid[{Grid /@ (per /. {a_, b_, c_} :> {{a, b}, {c, ""}})}, Dividers -> All]
```

[image]